# AngularJS and internet explorer 10: Curly braces substitution is not happening

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer

I have an angularjs app which works on all real browsers. The problem is with internet explorer 10.

I have done a lot of stuff like this in the app

```
<div style="font-size: {{data.font_size}}px"></div>
```

While this works fine on firefox, safari and chrome, it simply does not work with internet explorer.

To illustrate the problem I have created a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/3328/ Try it with chrome and internet explorer. Font size is 30 in chrome but is not in IE.

I would be glad if someone could tell me why that would be the case and if there is anything I can do other than reimplement the whole thing.

Even if I were reimplement the app to have no double curly braces in style attribute, ng-src still needs to have curly braces.

Comment: You should use ng-class in this case. IE10 has many issues with {{}}

Comment: The above thing is just an illustration, things like ng-src etc need curly braces to be there. What do I do then?

Comment: Instead of using an illustration consider reproducing your problem in fiddle or jsbin with a real example

Comment: The problem is reproduced in the jsfiddle. You can see it. I do not neeed to put my actual code

Comment: I had this same issue trying to use {{}} with style attribute. I changed to a css class, and applied It using ng-class

Comment: You need to put all angular code inside HTML attributes.

Comment: @YogeshMangaj I am not really sure I understand that

Comment: Read the 5th point under 'Short version' here http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this problem by using `ng-style` like this:

Markup:

```
<div custom-directive ng-style="setWidth()"></div>
```

Angular:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
  scope.setWidth = function() {
    return { "width": "200px" }
  }
}
```

ng-style expects an object which has a key as the CSS style name and the value as the value for the corresponding style. This works in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to change double braces that comes form AngularJS and check it. It will work with other characters such as `{[{data.font_size}]}/` To make them workable you need to declare them in Angular module like:

```
ModuleApp = angular.module('ModuleApp', []);

    ModuleApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
      $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{');
      $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}');
    });
```

also check that if your angular code gets initializes. You can put all angular code in block below

```
(function(){
//ALL AANGULAR CODE

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the scope variable inside ng-style, like this:

```
<div ng-style="{font-size: data.font_size}"></div>
```

Make sure your data.font_size has "px" appended to it.