# IE10 Select tag show up with curly brackets

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-10

For starter, I've been trying to reproduce this bug in a smaller case but failed.
So I'm just going to put out whatever info I've got so far.

I have a directive (directiveA) that calls another directive (directiveB).
The directiveB contains a `<select>` tag with `ng-model='fileId'`.
The option list is populated with ng-repeated based on a fileList array, with the selected set to a variable (selectedFile) as well.
The user then is allowed to upload a new file. When a new file is uploaded through AJAX API call, it will return with a new list of files from the server. I then update the fileList with the returned list.
I also update the selectedFile and fileId as well with the newly updated file.
However, when the fileId is updated, the option will only show {{fileName}}, instead of its bounded value. Clicking on the dropdown will then fix the binding.

```
<select ng-model='fileId'>
  <option ng-repeat="p in fileList" selected={selectedFileId == p.fileId}>{{p.fileName}}</option>
</select>
```

js

```
...
//AJAX call, return a result
s.fileList = result.items;
s.fileId = result.newId;
s.selectedfileId = result.newId;
```

Just wondering if any of you have encountered similar problem because it only happens in IE.

Comment: someone suggested a possible solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22227820/angularjs-and-internet-explorer-10-curly-braces-substitution-is-not-happening

Answer (score 6):

Use ng-option attribute for the select tag instead of ng-repeat on the option tag and all works well. A key consideration is to have the select value for your drop down match the model value.

```
<select ng-model='selectedfileId' ng-options='file.id as file.name for  file in fileList' ></select>
```

more details here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions